# Angular - Ignore element in NgFor

Tags: angular

The question is simple.

I want to iterate elements in a list. But... i need to compare if some values was equals, in this case ignores this element in the loop and continue. The code

```
 <li *ngFor="let secondary of location.contador.gateways" ngIf="location.contador.gateway != secondary.unidadVenta">{{secondary.TEST}}</li>
```

As we can see i try compare values in ng If but doesn't works as i expected.

Somebody know the right way to do this?

Comment: I think this solution, even if you can do it would result in a lot of bugs in the future. The safe way is to do the filter in the .ts behind the component

Comment: It's better to do that inside the `component.ts`. You can't use two structural directives on one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `component.ts` you can do something like this inside a lifecycle hook or any function:

```
this.location.contador.gateways = this.location.contador.gateways.filter((secondary) => {
 return location.contador.gateway != secondary.unidadVenta;
})
```

If you want to filter in your template then you can use a nested tag inside the `li` tag:

```
<li *ngFor="let secondary of location.contador.gateways">
 <span *ngIf="location.contador.gateway != secondary.unidadVenta">
 {{secondary.TEST}}
 </span>
</li>
```

You have to use a nested tag because you can't use two structural directives(`ngFor`, `ngIf`) on the same tag.

**UPDATE**

Using ng-container is better because you don't have to introduce unnecessary tags just for the purpose of using `*ngIf`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let secondary of location.contador.gateways">
 <li *ngIf="location.contador.gateway != secondary.unidadVenta">
  {{secondary.TEST}}
 </li>
</ng-container>
```

See [this](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue).

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-container` to wrap around the `<li>` tag:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let secondary of location.contador.gateways">
   <li *ngIf="location.contador.gateway != secondary.unidadVenta">
     {{secondary.TEST}}
   </li>
</ng-container>
```